# marker.iconView?.addSubview(UIButton) not clickable with Gmaps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

hi i create my custom marker.iconview

```
marker.iconView = CustomMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 301, height: 36))
```

here is my custom marker view

```
import UIKit

class CustomMarkerView: UIView {

var logo = UIImage()
var adress = UILabel()
var price = UILabel()
var icon_like = UIImage(named: "icon_like")
var icon_direction = UIImage(named: "icon_direction")

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addCustomView()
}

init(frame: CGRect, adress: String, price: String, logo: String) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.adress.text = adress
    self.price.text = price
    self.logo = UIImage(named: logo)!
    self.addCustomView()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addCustomView() {
    let layerBG = CALayer()
    layerBG.frame.size.width = 201
    layerBG.frame.size.height = 36
    layerBG.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bgMarkerView")!).cgColor
    layerBG.position = CGPoint(x: 201, y: 18)
    self.layer.addSublayer(layerBG)
}
```

then i add more custom elements in this view in my view controller

```
func addInternalElements(adress: String, price: String, logo: String) {
    let logoView = UIView()

    let logoImg = UIImage(named: logo)
    let logoImage = UIImageView(image: logoImg)
    logoView.addSubview(logoImage)
    setMarkerLogoConstraint(logoView: logoView, logoImage: logoImage)

    let adressLabel = UILabel()
    adressLabel.font = UIFont(name: "helveticaneuecyr-roman", size: 9)!
    adressLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    adressLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    adressLabel.text = adress

    let priceLabel = UILabel()
    priceLabel.font = UIFont(name: "helveticaneuecyr-roman", size: 11.2)!
    priceLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    priceLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    priceLabel.text = price

    let icon_like = UIImage(named: "icon_like")
    let likeBtn = UIButton()
    likeBtn.setImage(icon_like, for: .normal)
    likeBtn.setImage(icon_like, for: .selected)
    likeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    likeBtn.tag = 5
    likeBtn.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true

    self.topBarView.addSubview(btnProfileTopBar)
    setProfileIconConstraints()

    self.marker.iconView?.addSubview(logoView)
    self.marker.iconView?.addSubview(adressLabel)
    self.marker.iconView?.addSubview(priceLabel)
    self.marker.iconView?.addSubview(likeBtn)
    self.marker.iconView?.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true

    setLogoViewMarkerConstraints(logoView: logoView)
    setAdressMarkerConstraints(label: adressLabel, logoView: logoView)
    setPriceMarkerConstraints(label: priceLabel, logoView: logoView)
    setLikeBtnMarkerConstraints(btn: likeBtn)
}
```

all looks good but uibutton doesn't clickable(likeBtn.addTarget doesn't work), if i implement this method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    return false
}
```

i don't understand how i understand that i click on correct button(there will be more buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this problem created custom icon view across infoWindow